# Object doesn't support property or method 'autocomplete'

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

```
@model IEnumerable<ModelClass.DhoniRegistry>
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    <b> Dhoni Name  </b>
    @Html.TextBox("SearchTerm", null, new { id = "txtSearch" })
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}    

<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ()
    {
        $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({ source: '@Url.Action("ASDhoniName")' });
    });
</script>
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult ASDhoniName(string SearchTerm)
{
    DhoniRegistryBusinessSer dhoniBisSer = new DhoniRegistryBusinessSer();
    List<string> dhoniReg;
    dhoniReg = dhoniBisSer.ListDhoniRegistry().Where(x => x.DhoniName.StartsWith(SearchTerm))
        .Select(y => y.DhoniName).ToList();
    return Json(dhoniReg,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: need to return two property in list  value and label.

Comment: You have 2 copies of `jquery-ui` and should remove one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing/wrongly placed `jQuery/ jQuery UI.js/ autocomplete.js` files.
Also you have added two copies of `jquery-ui`. Remove one.

Here's the order to include files

1. jQuery.js
2. jQuery UI.js
3. autocomplete.js

Add the following before autocomplete

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" />
```

Comment: I think I add lot of unwanted Scripts bro

Comment: Yes you are adding 2 copies of `jquery-ui`. Remove one